# Reformulate some summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a way to reformulate the following equations (leaving `N(...)` alone on the left-hand side):

$$N(t)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a}\sum_{c=1}^{b}\sum_{d=1}^{c}d$$
$$N(t)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a}\sum_{c=1}^{b}\sum_{d=1}^{c}d^2$$
$$N(t)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a}\sum_{c=1}^{b}\sum_{d=1}^{c}d/3$$
$$N(t,x)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a}\sum_{c=1}^{b}\sum_{d=1}^{c}x^d$$
$$N(t,x)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a}\sum_{c=1}^{b}\sum_{d=1}^{c}x^{d-b}$$

Same kind of question for "undefined-length equations"

$$N(t)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a-1}\sum_{c=1}^{b-1}\sum_{d=1}^{c-1}\sum_{e=1}^{d-1}...\sum_{w=1}^{1}z$$
$$N(t)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a-1}\sum_{c=1}^{b-1}\sum_{d=1}^{c-1}\sum_{e=1}^{d-1}...\sum_{w=1}^{1}d$$
$$N(t)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a-1}\sum_{c=1}^{b-1}\sum_{d=1}^{c-1}\sum_{e=1}^{d-1}...\sum_{w=1}^{1}z/3$$
$$N(t,x)=\sum_{a=1}^{t}\sum_{b=1}^{a-1}\sum_{c=1}^{b-1}\sum_{d=1}^{c-1}\sum_{e=1}^{d-1}...\sum_{w=1}^{1}x^{c-e}$$

Comment: What do you mean by reformulate? To compute?

Comment: I meant to write differently. like $\frac{x^2}{4}$ is rewritten into $\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2$. I don't know if it's feasible to give a better look to these equations! is it? What do you mean "to compute"?